# CookieSecurePolicy- Website does not login after adding CookieSecurePolicy

Tags: .net-6.0

Our QA build stays on the login page after adding the following lines of code. The website has a http URL. It is not SSL Enabled.
It always redirects to /AccountLogin/SignIn?ReturnUrl=/

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
                ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
                : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```

How do I troubleshoot this? When I point code to the QA environment, cookie policy is being set to 'SameAsRequest'. Can I somehow see this setting on a browser?
I tried to make our development environment point to http not ssl but I cannot reproduce this issue. I also tried to use the QA build environment and run our code. Either way I am able to login. It does not work when going to the QA build website. How do I know what is causing the problem?
After entering the credentials, it just stays on the sign page as if its not processing something

Comment: `CookieSecurePolicy.Always` means the cookie requires `https` on the server. You can set both to `CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest`.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is a QA Lane. So the securepolicy is being set to 'Always' which means it is requiring https. But why am I not able to reproduce it? Is it because we have an additional app.UseHttpsRedirection() in the Program.cs?

Comment: You should obviously not have `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` if you don't have `https`!

Comment: May be production has https just not QA lanes. I still want to know why am I not able to reproduce the login page issue even when I connect my code to the QA lane and use http